# How do I parse this kind of json in Python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, math

```
[
  {
    "sets": "{\"sets\":[[15,12,10,16,22],[1,3,14,14,21],[18,18,19,4,6],[10,23,12,6,13],[4,3,16,6,3],[24,14,20,10,19],[19,16,2,18,9],[8,14,17,11,25],[4,20,4,24,13]],\"worn\":[1,3,4,6,7]}"
  }
]
```

This looks really weird to me an idk what to do. I need to make the `worn` section relate to the ones in `sets`. Like I need the 1st list, 3rd list, 4th list, 6th list, and 7th list. The 1st list should connect to `[15,12,10,16,22]` for example. I've tried `set['worn'][0]` which says returns a KeyError since `worn` is not a key. I've also tried `set['sets'][-1]` in attempt to get the final result which I'd think is the list after `worn`, but it actually just returns the entire block, since the actual Key seems to be the first `sets` and not the second.

I want to learn how to interpret this in the future, but my goal for this is to get the 5 numbers after `worn` and find the corresponding `sets` for those numbers, then add the first value of each list together, the 2nd value of each together, etc, up until 5 are added together.

Loading json with:

```
            scan = f"link"
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
                async with cs.get(scan) as r:
                    set = json.loads(await r.text())
```

Comment: ``import json; json.loads(data[0]['sets'])`` ??

Comment: ```scan = f"link"
   async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
    async with cs.get(scan) as r:
     set = json.loads(await r.text())``` It keeps giving me TypeError when I try but maybe I can't use this method for loading this kind of json? I've never had to use it before. If I can use this, can you give me an example of what you mean? The json is not mine. it's something online

Comment: I can't load your string into `json.loads()` either. If there's no way to make it compatible with `json.loads()`, it's possible to get where you want using standard python list and string manipulation techniques.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I will try. Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers worked for me and kept giving me different errors but Yuri's solution helped me to try and see it from a different perspective. I'm not sure why the json wasn't loading with the suggested solutions but I ended up having to use `eval` to get it to display what I wanted. Here is what I did:

```
            scan = f"link"
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
                async with cs.get(scan) as r:
                    set = json.loads(await r.text())
                    set = set[0]['sets']
                    set = eval(set)
                    setW = set['worn']
```

I don't understand eval too much other than a lot of people saying to avoid using it, but after using eval on the json, it allowed me to access the other keys and proceed with what I needed to do next.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat fancy JSON. It is an array with the single element, which is an object "sets". This object is a *string*:

```
"{\"sets\":[[15,12,10,16,22],[1,3,14,14,21],[18,18,19,4,6],[10,23,12,6,13],[4,3,16,6,3],[24,14,20,10,19],[19,16,2,18,9],[8,14,17,11,25],[4,20,4,24,13]],\"worn\":[1,3,4,6,7]}"
```

This string is a valid JSON object and can be parsed.

json.loads errors are caused by newline character `'\n'`. Reading this JSON from file or file alike object fixes errors.
I saved your json to a file.

```
$ cat s.json 
[
  {
    "sets": "{\"sets\":[[15,12,10,16,22],[1,3,14,14,21],[18,18,19,4,6],[10,23,12,6,13],[4,3,16,6,3],[24,14,20,10,19],[19,16,2,18,9],[8,14,17,11,25],[4,20,4,24,13]],\"worn\":[1,3,4,6,7]}"
  }
]
```

and parsed it.

```
import json

with open('s.json') as f: 
    j = json.load(f)[0]
j1 = json.loads(j['sets'])

sets = j1['sets']
worn = j1['worn']

print(sets)
print(worn)
```

Results:

```
[[15, 12, 10, 16, 22], [1, 3, 14, 14, 21], [18, 18, 19, 4, 6], [10, 23, 12, 6, 13], [4, 3, 16, 6, 3], [24, 14, 20, 10, 19], [19, 16, 2, 18, 9], [8, 14, 17, 11, 25], [4, 20, 4, 24, 13]]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: It's interesting that saving the string in a file and using `json.load()` works, but reading directly with `json.loads()` doesn't work.

Comment: @JackFleeting Reading from file (or directly from URL as file object) preepends \\ to newline char, so text can be valid Python string.